# the number of class files in a java package constant

Tags: java

I am new to java.My friend asked me this question today And i am looking for an answer to it.
How to make the number of class files in a package, constant? 
i.e., even though one can access that package,they should not be able to add any new class to the exisiting package.

Answer (score 5):

You want sealed packages. Once sealed, all classes from a package must come from the same JAR file. It basically boils down to adding the package to the manifest:

```
Name: myCompany/myPackage/
Sealed: true
```

- See [Sealing packages within a jar file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is called *sealing* the package and works on the level of jar files.

From the [official trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html):

> Packages within JAR files can be optionally *sealed*, which means that **all classes defined in that package must be archived in the same JAR file**. You might want to seal a package, for example, to ensure version consistency among the classes in your software.

To clarify: Since the classes must come from the same jar file, no one can add classes to your package, since the new classes wouldn't come from your jar file.